# How to filter a request that has an invalid parameter in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, filter, jax-rs, resteasy, query-string

By "invalid" I mean a parameter that is not expected.

For example:

```
@Path("/")
public interface ExampleInterface {
    @GET
    @Path("/example")
    public Response test(
        @QueryParam("param1") String param1,
        @QueryParam("param2") String param2
    );
}
```

And then I call `".../example?param3=foo"`

Comment: That looks like an invalid URL for your handler. Isn't it?

Comment: You can make use of Per Resource Method Filters and Interceptors...

Comment: If a parameter is not expected, it can be ignored.

Comment: What exactly is your problem or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to redirect the user to a "400 Bad Request" page if an unexpected parameter is sent, without using RESTEasy, using only the JAX-RS specs. @LutzHorn, I know it can be ignored, but it's a project requisite.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check use a [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) and compare the passed parameters with the defined parameters:

```
@Provider
public class RequestParamFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        Set<String> validParams = new HashSet<String>();
        Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
        for (Annotation[] annos : method.getParameterAnnotations()) {
            for (Annotation anno : annos) {
                if (anno instanceof QueryParam) {
                    validParams.add(((QueryParam) anno).value());
                }
            }
        }
        for (String param : servletRequest.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
            if (!validParams.contains(param)) {
                requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Don't forget that [ServletRequest#getParameterMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()) returns a Map which contains both - query string parameters and parameters passed in the body of the request. So maybe you need to parse the query string yourself.

Note: This won't speed up your application.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the accepted answer. It is very helpful and I also use it. I'm providing a modified version, with the following changes:

- removed the servletRequest coming in via Context Annotation. This is not needed as the request is a parameter of the filter method itself.
- added the imports, as there can be a lot of consufsion about the diffrent classes with the same name (Method, Annotation, ContainerRequestContext, ...)
- also added the name of the missing parameter to the error message

-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class UnexpectedParameterFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        Set<String> validParams = new HashSet<String>();
        Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
        for (Annotation[] annos : method.getParameterAnnotations()) {
            for (Annotation anno : annos) {
                if (anno instanceof QueryParam) {
                    validParams.add(((QueryParam) anno).value());
                }
            }
        }

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters = requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters();
        for (String param : queryParameters.keySet()) {
            if (!validParams.contains(param)) {
                requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("unexpected paramter: "+param).build());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There is one difference between between `requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters()` and `servletRequest.getParameterMap()`. The latter will also contain parameters of posted form data. I would agree that in this example the former makes more sense. Thanks!